# FreeBSD -no internet access -no packages

Tags: freebsd, php5, package-management, packages

I just used this command:

```
make -DBATCH install clean
```

and realized that I don't have access to internet from FreeBSD. 
If I type the address manually the browser doesn't let me see them.

Can someone tell me if there is a place to retrieve a full package of `php5` installed full and just upload it or some clue to my problem?

[image: http://prntscr.com/9hrmn2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download php5 and all those dependencies to install all that manually. Those can be found at the addresses shown from where they are trying to fetch them, or you can look them up in each individual port, or you can go to http://freshports.org/ and find the addresses of all that.

Of course, this is all a bit of work.